# Locally built zsh can't find its own function files

Tags: software-installation, zsh, compiling, autoconf, automake

Okay, so the Linux server I use at work doesn't have Zsh installed on it and I don't have root access, so I manually built and installed zsh to `"$HOME/usr"` (I've done this with other programs such as `colordiff`, `rlwrap`, and `dateutils`, and they all function perfectly well) and it runs just fine **except** that when I specify `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit; autoload -U colors && colors` it gives me the following errors:

```
/home/foobar/.zshrc:16: compinit: function definition file not found
/home/foobar/.zshrc:17: colors: function definition file not found
```

Now I've checked and rechecked and everything is installed as it should be:

*(Output from `ls -R usr`)*

```
usr/share/zsh:
5.2  site-functions

usr/share/zsh/5.2:
functions  help  scripts

usr/share/zsh/5.2/functions:
Calendar  Chpwd  Completion  Exceptions  MIME  Misc  Newuser  Prompts  TCP  VCS_Info  Zftp  Zle
```

Here's the script that I wrote to configure and build ZSH:

```bash
_prefix="$HOME/pre"

cd "zsh-5.2"

prepare() {
  # set correct keymap path
  # FIXME this may not work at RRD since their Linux servers aren't Arch Linux based
  sed -i 's#/usr/share/keymaps#/lib/kbd/keymaps#g' Completion/Unix/Command/_loadkeys

  # Fix usb.ids path
  # FIXME I don't know if this is necessary/will even work at RRD
  sed -i 's#/usr/share/misc/usb.ids#/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids#g' Completion/Linux/Command/_lsusb

  # Remove unneeded and conflicting completion scripts
  # FIXME this definitely probably won't work at RRD
  #for _fpath in AIX BSD Cygwin Darwin Debian Mandriva openSUSE Redhat Solaris; do
  #  rm -rf Completion/$_fpath
  #  sed "s#\s*Completion/$_fpath/\*/\*##g" -i Src/Zle/complete.mdd
  #done
  #rm Completion/Linux/Command/_{pkgtool,rpmbuild}
}

build() {
  ./configure --prefix="$_prefix"/usr \
    --docdir="$_prefix"/usr/share/doc/zsh \
    --htmldir="$_prefix"/usr/share/doc/zsh/html \
    --enable-etcdir="$_prefix"/etc/zsh \
    --enable-zshenv="$_prefix"/etc/zsh/zshenv \
    --enable-zlogin="$_prefix"/etc/zsh/zlogin \
    --enable-zlogout="$_prefix"/etc/zsh/zlogout \
    --enable-zprofile="$_prefix"/etc/zsh/zprofile \
    --enable-zshrc="$_prefix"/etc/zsh/zshrc \
    --disable-maildir-support \
    --with-term-lib='ncursesw' \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-function-subdirs \
    --enable-fndir="$_prefix"/usr/share/zsh/functions \
    --enable-scriptdir="$_prefix"/usr/share/zsh/scripts \
    --with-tcsetpgrp \
    --enable-pcre \
    --enable-zsh-secure-free \
    --enable-multibyte
  make
}
\
package() {
  make install
  make install.info install.html
}

make distclean
prepare
build
check
package
```

Is there anything that I'm missing or forgetting, like is there a specific option that `configure` sets that will instruct Zsh specifically where to find its site-functions and other functions.  Mostly I'm super confused because it's not like Zsh *doesn't* know where its site-functions are because it installed them in the expected place, albeit it's not in /usr.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I ran strace on zsh and there's a huge list of files that Zsh can't find:

```
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXbsrt/lib", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/FJSVXmeft/lib", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/syncsort/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/syncsort/lib/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/syncsort/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/rrdcom/load/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/rrdcom/load/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/rrdcom/load/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/cobol_utils/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/cobol_utils/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/cobol_utils/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/cobol_utils/tls", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/cobol_utils/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/cobol_utils/x86_64", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/cobol_utils/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/apps/cobol_utils", 0x7fffa0839490) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(11, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(11, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libnss_vas4.so.2", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/tls/x86_64/libvtsmartcache.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/quest/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa0838e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/tls/libvtsmartcache.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/quest/lib64/tls", 0x7fffa0838e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/x86_64/libvtsmartcache.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/quest/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fffa0838e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/quest/lib64/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/rts/lib/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/code1_v370/c1p/lib/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/lcpv650/lcp/lib/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/FJSVcbl64/lib/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/syncsort/lib/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/apps/rrdcom/load/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/opt/quest/vas/.qas_id_dbg", 0x7fffa08397d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tmp/.vasipc_timeout", 0x7fffa0839640) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tmp/.vasipc_timeout", 0x7fffa08396d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/opt/quest/vas/.qas_id_call", 0x7fffa08397d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/zshenv.zwc", 0x7fffa0839a80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/zshenv", 0x7fffa08399f0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/zshenv", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Some of the files are due to the configure options that I'm passing to Zsh, some of which I need to change; of particular interest, however, are the following:

```
stat("/home/foobar/.zshenv.zwc", 0x7fffa0839a80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/foobar/.zshrc.zwc", 0x7fffa0837f00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun.zwc", 0x7fffa08332d0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun/compinit.zwc", 0x7fffa0833240) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun/compinit", 0x7fffa08331b0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/sfun/compinit", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun.zwc", 0x7fffa08332d0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun/colors.zwc", 0x7fffa0833240) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sfun/colors", 0x7fffa08331b0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/sfun/colors", R_OK)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce this installing zsh 5.2 on Redhat 6 copying your `./configure` args. Perhaps run it under `strace` or `sysdig` to see what files yours is looking for?

Comment: @thrig so it seems that `$fpath` determines where Zsh looks for the function files, however, for whatever reason my build doesn't seem to include the `*.zwc` files...